# QT plugins compilation issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a serious issue with QtPlugin. I try to build a plugin from an interface, named dictionary:

```
class dictionary
{
private:
   ... some private members
public:
   ~dictionary();

   ... some no virtual methods

   virtual void collectData()=0;
   virtual void collectOperator()=0;
   virtual void collectControl()=0;
};

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(CDictionnary, "shinoe.cameleon.dictionary/2.0")
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

I have implemented dictionary in a blankdictionary class declared like this (blankdictionary.h) in a blankdictionary project.

The .pro file:

```
!include(../../../configuration.pri)

QT       += core gui

TARGET = blanktarget
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += plugin

#dictionary interface includes
!include(../../../machine/kernel/includekernel.pri)

SOURCES += blankdictionary.cpp
HEADERS += blankdictionary.h
```

The blankdictionary.h file:

```
class blankdictionary : public dictionary {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_INTERFACES(dictionary)
public:
   blankdictionary();
   void collectData();
   void collectOperator();
   void collectControl();
};
```

At the end of my blankdictionary.cpp file I have:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(blanktarget, blankdictionary)
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

At compile, it returns this error:

```
blankdictionary.cpp: In function 'QObject* qt_plugin_instance()':
blankdictionary.cpp:20: error: no match for 'operator=' in '_instance = (operator new(44u), (<statement>, ((blankdictionary*)<anonymous>)))'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtCore/qpointer.h:65: note: candidates are: QPointer<T>& QPointer<T>::operator=(const QPointer<T>&) [with T = QObject]
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtCore/qpointer.h:67: note:                 QPointer<T>& QPointer<T>::operator=(T*) [with T = QObject]
```

any idea?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think the problems comes from here:
     
    "[...] Making an application extensible through plugins involves the following steps:
        Define a set of interfaces (classes with only pure virtual functions) used to talk to the plugins. [...]"

From this source: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/plugins-howto.html.

So, I think i have to make dictionary interface a class with only pure virtual functions.

I try it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another problem (as well as the one you have mentioned in your comment), is that you have declared the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the `blankdictionary` class, but then not derived it from `QObject`.

Comment: Yes, blankdictionary must be an implementation of QObject in this case or I have, as you have mentioned, to remove the Q_OBJECT macro. Now it works ! Thanks !